# change width in a relative node

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some CSS problems. I have a parent with a 400px width, and I want the children (wich is relative to the parent so I can put it in the middle of the parent, and make his z-index bigger) to have a 200 width so that he wont get out of the parent. The children are jquery selectable.

( just the first drawer works in the top, right)

The main css:

```
  .sortableIt { list-style-type: none; position:relative;top:-250px;left:20px;margin: 0; z-index:1000;padding: 0; width: 100px; height:100px }
  .sortableIt li { margin: 1px 5px 1px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 35px; height: 35px; text-align: center; }
    .sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; /*width: 1200px; */}
  .sortable li {/*background-color:yellow;*/ margin: 0px 0px 0px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 360px; height: 72px; text-align: center; }
```

The html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<li id="sertar111?" style="z-index:500"> 
<img id="sertar11" class="sertar" ONCLICK="openS(this)" style="position: relative;z-index: 500;aligh:center;" src="img/sertar1.png">
<ul id="ui items" class="sortableIt" style="visibility:hidden;" >
  <li id="asd" class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `style="z-index=10000"`

Comment: That is not the problme I want to solve... but thnx, I fix it.

Comment: I didn't say it was an answer, just a typo.

Comment: The problem can be solved by max-width: 50%. Thanks anyway